# Hamburger not changing to X

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, hamburger-menu

I’m trying to create a hamburger button which turns to `×` when clicked. Everything is working fine, I just can’t make the `×` sign in a perfect shape. I wanna know how many pixels should I translate the top and bottom bars of the hamburger menus. I checked some tutorials, they do the same thing I did,but for somereason mine is not working.

This is my code:

Thank you for the help in advance.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

  hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //Toggle
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");

    //Animate
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = "";
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${
          index / 7 + 0.5
        }s`;
      }
    });

    //hamburger animation
    hamburger.classList.toggle("toggle");
  });
};

navSlide();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:ital,wght@1,100&display=swap");
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
}

.logo {
  color: #5b3b97;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: initial;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: #5b3b97;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #5b3b97;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 10vh;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(40px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1.5;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0;
}
.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Navigation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <h4>Bargain Technologies Pvt.Ltd</h4>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Companies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="hamburger">
        <div class="line 1"></div>
        <div class="line 2"></div>
        <div class="line 3"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note: if it is a button (like a button that toggles the menu) then you should definitely use a `<button type="button">` element. You get click event, keyboard functionality out of the box. Don't use a div for this.

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: hamburger is not defined` and assume some code is missing.

Comment: @showdev yeah he didnt declare the `hamburger` variable in the code snippet

Comment: @showdev The code is updated

Comment: @cloned You mean,I change  `<div class=line 1"></div>`  in  `<buttton>`  ?

Comment: No, you change `<div class="hamburger">` into `<button type="button">` ... You can leave the `<span>` inside the button, style it as you wish. Just use a button for everything that should be clicked (and which is not a link, use `<a href="">` for links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name in your `class="line 1"` change to `class="line1"`.
There are few things...
Declare your `.hamburger` as `position: relative;` and give `width` and `height`:

```
  .hamburger {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 25px;
    height: 20px;
  }
```

than, `.hamburger div` set as `position: absolute`:

```
  .hamburger div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #5b3b97;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
```

, make correct position for every single line(`.hamburger .line1 && .hamburger .line2 && .hamburger .line3`):

```
  .hamburger .line1 {
    top: 0;
  }

  .hamburger .line2 {
    top: 50%;
  }
  .hamburger .line3 {
    top: 100%;
  }
```

finally rotate for 135deg `transform: rotate(135deg);` and position top for before and after set like `top: 50%;` and mid line define `display: none;`:

```
  .toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    top: 50%;
  }
  .toggle .line2 {
    display: none;
  }
  .toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    top: 50%;
  }
```

Comment: One problem in here, the cross doesn't appear fully. Only half of it appears

Comment: Did you transform .toggle .line1 in negative value `transform: rotate(-135deg)` and .toggle .line3 positive 135deg `transform: rotate(135deg)`

Comment: It works fine in my case. Two of this after and before lines do transformation and make a cross.
Can you describe what did you mean when you said half of it appears?

Comment: [like this](https://photos.app.goo.gl/1ogaK1EgX1kiUU1z6)

Comment: Ok. Now I'm sure that you definitely didn't set `.toggle .line1 {top:50%;}` and `.toggle .line2 {transform: rotate(135deg);
  top: 50%;}` 
You have both of these properties there.

Comment: Oh yeah,missed the `top:50%`